# ASP.NET MVC throws error when id is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a *publicly* available controller (The action **cannot** be hidden under any security attribute) . The controller has an action which is available *publicly* as well.

Following is a sample structure of the controller :

```
 public SomeController : Controller {


       [HttpGet] 
       public ActionResult show(int id){

       }

 }
```

The action has a `id` field which is required. However throws an error which unnecessary adds to the logs when someone enters a malformed URL without the required `id` (or when search engine bots hit the a URL with the required `id`).

What should be the ideal solution to deal with this solution.

Possible solutions that come to my mind are :

- Set the id as Nullable (int? id) and explicitly handle the case of not having a value by redirecting the caller to some other page showing appropriate errors
- **explicitly** send a 404 error

Is there a generic way using Attributes to do this?

P.S : (to be specific) by explicit I mean writing if else conditions to handle such cases per controller.

I would appreciate any hints in the right direction.

Comment: I've used a nullable for this same purpose before. I would go with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a route constraint. This will help the router throw out URLs earlier (resulting in a 404) rather than later (the route is valid, goes to action, action barfs because a parameter is missing).

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs

Example default route (potentially replacing the existing one in your global.asax.cx):

```
// order is important; more specific routes to less specific routes is what you want
//
// default index action, with no ID
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default_Index",
    "{controller}/",
    new {controller="Home", action="Index"}
 );

// default create action, with no ID
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default_Create",
    "{controller}/Create",
    new {controller="Home", action="Create"}
 );

// default action requiring an ID (such as EDIT)
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new {controller="Home", action="Index"},
    new {id = @"\d+" }
 );
```

Comment: Nice! But if there are multiple publicly available controllers, would I need to add a route for each of them?

Comment: I have a default route defined which goes to the index action where the id is Optional

Comment: I'll update my answer with a general route that you could potentially use, rather than adding routes for each controller.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to return 404 status with a custom error page because some one is requesting a resource that doesn't exists.

You can make it as a Nullable type, if it can return a result which represents that request otherwise return 404 status.

For e.g. action method `Index(int? id)` could return list of items, if id is null or return that specific item. Depending on your business scenario.